# How to queue music by using the play command

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm working on a Discord music Bot and I'm now at the part that I want the bot to be able to add a song to the queue whenever someone commands it to play a song while it is already playing one.
(I don't want to have a seperate "queue" command, I want it to do it automatically)

So far this is my code (only the functions that matter):

```
async def play_queue(self, ctx: discord.ext.commands.context.Context):
        audio = await self.get_audio(self.queue.pop(0))
        vc = ctx.voice_client
        if not self.is_playing(ctx):
            vc.play(audio)
        if len(self.queue) > 0:
            await self.play_queue(ctx)

@commands.command(name="play", pass_ctx=True)
    async def play(self, ctx: discord.ext.commands.context.Context, url=""):
        await self.handle_connected(ctx)
        self.queue.append(url)
        # send a message to inform that a song has been queued or being played
        await self.send_playing(ctx)
        await self.play_queue(ctx)
```

I can Q 1 song at a time but can't queue multiple because it's stuck in the while loop

Comment: Your code is more complex than necessary. Adopt this strategy: unconditionally enqueue new song. As a separate matter, if we're idle and there's something in the queue, play it.

Comment: but in order for a song to be played we need to run the function again don't we ?

Comment: I'm suggesting that `play()` would (1.) enqueue a song, then (2.) call a helper that immediately dequeues a song if speaker is idle. It's the same helper that should run when a song finishes playing. I'm shooting for separation of concerns, so we independently maintain a queue and keep the speaker busy while the queue is non-empty.

Comment: sorry for being ignorant but I'm new to programming.
once play has finished running it exits the function.
now, when the speaker is idle I want play to dequeue from the queue and play it.
but how do I do that without a loop? 

I simplified my code, hope this is better now

Comment: Yes, looks good. One nice aspect of simplified control flow is now it's easier to add `print(...)` logging statements so you can see how much it has done thus far, and where it got stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done it by using the modules: threading, asyncio

This is the code segment that works:

```
async def idle_speaker(self, ctx: discord.ext.commands.context.Context):
    while self.is_playing(ctx):
        time.sleep(1)
    await self.play_queue(ctx)

def wait_for_idle(self, ctx: discord.ext.commands.context.Context):
    self.thread = True

    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

    loop.run_until_complete(self.idle_speaker(ctx))
    loop.close()
    self.thread = False

async def play_queue(self, ctx: discord.ext.commands.context.Context):
    if not self.is_playing(ctx):
        audio = await self.get_audio(self.queue.pop(0))
        ctx.voice_client.play(audio)

    if len(self.queue) > 0:
        playing_t = threading.Thread(target=self.wait_for_idle, name="Song_Listener", args=[ctx])
        playing_t.start()

@commands.command(name="play", pass_ctx=True)
async def play(self, ctx: discord.ext.commands.context.Context, url=""):
    await self.handle_connected(ctx)
    self.queue.append(url)
    print(self.queue, self.is_playing(ctx))

    # send a message to inform that a song has been queued or being played
    await self.send_playing(ctx)
    if not self.thread:
        await self.play_queue(ctx)
```